# How to connect Jupyterhub login with spawned notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, webrequest, http-proxy, jupyterhub

i am trying to make jupyterhub with CondorSpawner and LDAPauthentiator work, and I am struggeling with the following problem:

I have spawned a jupyter botebook via `jupyter notebook --port=53762` via htcondor and the spawner returns the correct ip and port number. After Jupyterhub starts to connect `http://localhost:53762/tree/user/u52383/vjfjfj/` to  but when the server redirects to the spawned notebook, it always crashes with the following 404 error (last 2 lines):

```
16:13:41.229 [ConfigProxy] info: Adding route /tree/user/gabriel/vjfjfj -> http://127.0.0.1:53762
16:13:41.229 [ConfigProxy] info: Route added /tree/user/gabriel/vjfjfj -> http://127.0.0.1:53762
16:13:41.230 [ConfigProxy] info: 201 POST /api/routes/tree/user/gabriel/vjfjfj
[I 2020-10-06 16:13:41.232 JupyterHub users:609] Server gabriel:vjfjfj is ready
[I 2020-10-06 16:13:41.232 JupyterHub log:174] 200 GET /tree/hub/api/users/gabriel/servers/vjfjfj/progress (u52383@::ffff:127.0.0.1) 10363.56ms
[I 2020-10-06 16:13:41.244 JupyterHub log:174] 302 GET /tree/hub/spawn-pending/gabriel/vjfjfj -> /tree/user/gabriel/vjfjfj (u52383@::ffff:127.0.0.1) 0.00ms
16:13:41.258 [ConfigProxy] error: 404 GET /login?next=%2Ftree%2Fuser%2Fgabriel%2Fvjfjfj
[I 2020-10-06 16:13:41.264 JupyterHub log:174] 200 GET /tree/hub/error/404?url=%2Flogin%3Fnext%3D%252Ftree%252Fuser%252Fgabriel%252Fvjfjfj (@127.0.0.1) 0.00ms
```

It looks like there is some error according to the jupyter notebook since it has been requested at that time

`[I 16:13:41.254 NotebookApp] 302 GET /tree/user/u52383/vjfjfj (127.0.0.1) 0.00ms`

and the error itself sounds like an login error `/login?next=%2Ftree%2Fuser%2Fgabriel%2Fvjfjfj`

Does anybody know what causes this crash? Or is there an error with spawning the notebook this way?

Thanks in advance

Gabriel

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this myself, the problem was a security block in the jupyter notebook.
By adding `--NotebookApp.token=''` the login was succesful.

Note that this is a little unsecure, since everyone on the server can now access the notebook